# can you use spark-shell programmatically

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

is it possible to run a spark-shell from a java or scala program? another words, start a spark-shell session inside a java program, pass spark code to it and read back the response, and continue the interaction inside the code.

Comment: Y U not just send the task

Comment: This makes littles sense to me. In what scenario would you want to do this? If you want to use Spark, just use it directly in your java code...

Comment: not sure which perspective all you are asking from. you do know that spark-shell is interactive. "send the task" is not interactive. spark-shell can run in parallel mode on top of yarn. "use Spark directly in your code" means how? spark-submit? run locally? which ever you are suggesting, is different from sending spark code to spark-shell interactively.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use spark-shell you can always call it from java and then capture its stdin and stdout to pass text and get responses.

```
OutputStream stdin = null;
InputStream stderr = null;
InputStream stdout = null;

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("spark-shell");
stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
stdout = process.getInputStream ();
```

But there is actually no reason doing so. Spark-Shell is mostly for learning and testing. Everything you can do from the shell you can do it from a Java app, even interactively.

Consider the following example:
You want to count errors and if they are more than 100 ask user if he wants to display them at the console. If they are less than 100 display them anyway:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://log.txt").filter(s -> s.contains("error"));
if(lines.count() > 100)
{
    System.out.println("Errors are more than 100 do you wish to display them? (y/n)");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    if(br.readLine().equals("y"))
    {
        List<String> errors = lines.collect();
        for(String s : errors)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
else
{
    List<String> errors = lines.collect();
    for(String s : errors)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I suppose stdin and out is the final fallback. But I know there must be a more direct way. For example there is a SparkILoop class which is essentially the interpreter used. The example you gave is technically interactive, but it hardly serves the purpose of a REPL. you may not know in advance 100 is the threshold or even line count is the key feature of interest.

Comment: If you know in advance all the key features then you can go with conditions and get to the right result. But if you don't know the features then why use a Java program to call spark-shell and not go to spark-shell from the beginning?

Comment: I think I got what you need! I searched what spark-shell calls and got to SparkILoop as you mentioned! From there I finally got to SparkIMain from scala-2.10 repl. The comments at the beginning mention:

***An interpreter for Scala code.***. The _compile()_ method loads a complete Scala file. The _interpret()_ method executes one line of Scala code at the request of the user. The _bind()_ method binds an object to a variable that can then be used by later interpreted code.

Comment: maybe you can help me get going. I tried     `val sparkIMain = new SparkIMain()
    val bindResult = sparkIMain.bind("a", "Int", 0, List[String]())
    var bVar = 0
    val bindResult1 = sparkIMain.bind("bVar", "Int", "b", List[String]())
    val result = sparkIMain.interpret("var b = a + 1")
    println("result = "  + bindResult1)` - different variation of b and bVar in bind(), but can not get the result for b out of the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution on top of `Spark 1.6.0` and `Scala 2.10`. Create `SparkIMain` with `Settings` and `bind` the variables and values associated with types.

```
import org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerSettings
class TestMain {
  def exec(): Unit = {
    val settings = new GenericRunnerSettings( println _ )
        settings.usejavacp.value = true
    val interpreter = new SparkIMain(settings)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestMain").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val methodChain =
      """
        val df = sqlContext.read
              .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
              .option("header", "false")
              .option("inferSchema", "true")
              .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
              .option("parserLib", "univocity")
              .load("example-data.csv")

        df.show()

      """
    interpreter.bind("sqlContext" ,"org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext", sqlContext)
    val resultFlag = interpreter.interpret(methodChain)
  }
}

object TestInterpreter{

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val testMain = new TestMain()
      testMain.exec()
      System.exit(0)
    }}
```

Comment: No one seems to understand what I am asking.  I am trying to get the value of b out of the interpreter. The bind() method does not work for that.