# Running Spark-Shell from JAVA interactively

Tags: shell, apache-spark, processbuilder

I am trying to build a UI which gives developers a utility to build their spark codes interactively.
For this, I want the capability to validate the spark queries by running the queries in a spark shell rather than spark-submit. I want to achieve this from my Java code. 
Is it doable? I am able to start the spark shell using ProcessBuilder but how to pass the subsequent commands and capture the spark shell output to display on screen?

```
//Spark shell
        builder = new ProcessBuilder("/Users/xyz/Downloads/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell");
```

Comment: maybe there is a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491887/can-you-use-spark-shell-programmatically